# apply move on a lambda closure

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

This might be a conceptual question. I am implementing functions taking `lambda` as parameters. However, I couldn't understand the exact type of a `lambda`. For example:

```
auto T = [] () { printf("hello world\n"); };
auto F = move(T);
T();  // print "hello world"
F();  // print "hello world"
```

I thought after calling `move` on `T`, the content of `T` disappeared. In other words, I expect the following behavior:

```
function<void> T = [] () { printf("hello world\n");};
auto F = move(F);
F();  // print "hello world"
T();  // throw error
```

Back to the original question, what is the best practice of passing/assigning a `lambda` to a class member of `function<void()>`? I saw many different answers, some using `const function<void()>&` and others suggesting template `F&&`

```
struct Foo {

  function<void()> f;

  // Option 1:
  void set_f(const function<void()>& in) {f=in;}

  // Option 2: template
  template <typename F>
  void set_f(F&& in) { // what to write here??? }  
}
```

Are these two options general enough to capture most input types?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to have a basic misunderstanding of what a compiler does with a lambda expression. Lambda expressions are transformed into functors with unique names. When you invoke the lambda you're simply calling the `operator()` of the functor.

So the lambda in your first example will create something like this

```
struct __uniquely_named_lambda
{
    void operator()() const
    {
        printf("hello world\n");
    }
};
```

If this lambda were storing any state, then `move`ing from it would move the state, but your lambda is stateless, so `move` does nothing; you can't strip out the body of `operator()` and move it elsewhere.

For example, these statements will produce the output `4 0 4`

```
std::string s{"Test"};
auto T = [s]() { std::cout << s.size() << ' '; };  // make a copy of s
T();
auto F = std::move(T);
T();
F();
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f72223096c597b1c)

---

`std::function` is a container that can accept any *callable* that matches the specified signature, and your lambda is one such callable. When you `move` the `std::function`, you're moving the callable target it stores into the destination. Trying to invoke the target on the original will then throw `bad_function_call`, this is very different from `move`ing a lambda.

---

I'd write you `set_f` member function as

```
template <typename F>
void set_f(F&& in)
{
    f = std::forward<F>(in);
}
```

`F` in your example is a forwarding reference, meaning it'll be able to accept either lvalues or rvalues passed by the caller. The assignment will then either copy assign or move assign the argument.

Comment: @dau_sama It would work insofar as `f` would be assigned the argument, but it may not do what the caller expects. If you called `set_f` with a non-`const` lvalue reference to `std::function` it would still `move` the argument, which is probably not what you want. If you want to always `move`, you should take `F` by value instead.